# Reducing code for animation of expanding menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I wonder if I can reduce the code to optimize it better?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-1, #menu-event-1').hover(function () {
        $('#menu-deco-1').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#menu-deco-1').stop().animate({
            right: -280
        }, 'fast');
    });
    $('#menu-2, #menu-event-2').hover(function () {
        $('#menu-deco-2').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#menu-deco-2').stop().animate({
            right: -280
        }, 'fast');
    });
    $('#menu-3, #menu-event-3').hover(function () {
        $('#menu-deco-3').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#menu-deco-3').stop().animate({
            right: -280
        }, 'fast');
    });
    $('#menu-4, #menu-event-4').hover(function () {
        $('#menu-deco-4').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#menu-deco-4').stop().animate({
            right: -280
        }, 'fast');
    });
    $('#menu-5, #menu-event-5').hover(function () {
        $('#menu-deco-5').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#menu-deco-5').stop().animate({
            right: -280
        }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@Bludream came quite close, he noticed the code that was copy pasted, turned the common parts into a function, and then he used a loop to execute everything. The error is in doing both animations on the hover event. This should work:

```
var mouseLeaveAnimation = { right: -280 };
var mouseEnterAnimation = { right: 0 };

for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

  $('#menu-' + i + ', #menu-event-' + i).hover(function() {
    $('#menu-deco-' + i).stop().animate(mouseEnterAnimation, 'fast');
  }, function() {
    $('#menu-deco-' + i).stop().animate(mouseLeaveAnimation, 'fast');
  });
}
```

Comment: ahh right!!  I didn't notice, he is using multiple function argument of hover method!!  this code is right

Comment: Thank you Konijn but your code don't work ^^

Comment: That is possible, present us with a working example with snippet or jsbin and we can present 100% working code. The idea of code review is too provide a review, not necessarily to provide the working code. But out of courtesy, if you provide a working snippet we tend to always provide you actually working code.

Answer (score 1):

of course you can,
I guess this would do it:

> ```
>   $(function() {
>     for (var index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
>         $('#menu-'+index+', #menu-event-'+index).hover(function () {
>             stomAnim( $('#menu-deco-'+index),true);
>             stomAnim( $('#menu-deco-'+index),false);
>         });
>     }
>     function stomAnim (obj,odd){
>         obj.stop().animate({
>             right: odd?0:-280
>         }, 'fast');
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: Thank you a lot but it does not work :'(

Comment: Change `$('#menu-'+index+',` to `$('#menu-'+index,`. That should do it.

Comment: @Abbas Does not work

Comment: @Flocon, don't just say it does not work!! tell us what error you get?? or post a code from http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: when I hover over the div #menu-1 or other, the animation does not work nothing... Not error syntaxe on the code by Bludream ?

Comment: so it means, code is correct! but you strategy is wrong, as I said send a jsfiddle